# Localizar un servicio a traves de python nmap

Tags: python

necesito obtener de una determinada subred, por ejemplo 10.0.0.0/24, los ip's que esten corriendo un servicio en especifico:
Ej: necesito saber cuales corren el servicio 'telnet' , y el me va devolviendo los ip q estan corriendo dicho servicio.
esto a traves de python-nmap,gracias

Comment: Hola, Rafael. La [documentación](http://xael.org/pages/python-nmap-en.html) de `python-nmap` está bastante clara, incluso tiene un ejemplo muy similar a lo que pides. ¿Podías indicar qué has probado y qué problemas te has encontrado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rafael!

El uso de esta biblioteca es bastante sencillo:

```
import nmap

info_scanning = nmap.PortScanner()

info_scanning.scan(hosts='10.0.0.0/24', arguments='-n -sP') 
#en arguments se usa la misma sintaxis del programa "nmap"
```

si tenés problemas con la biblioteca python-nmap, podrías instalar el programa nmap y luego manejarlo a través de python, mediante la biblioteca os. Debería ser algo como:

```
    import os
    os.system("nmap 10.0.0.*")
```